# How to get WIFI provider name when its connected to Android device

Tags: java, android, wifi

In my app I'm trying to get network provider name when my app is connected to wifi.
If I'm using getSSID it will return the name of wifi not the provider name, but i need to know the provider of the broadband

Example :
If WIFI connected to Airtel Broadband, provider will be Airtel, how to fetch the provider as Airtel.

Below snippet is the one I tried, but i didn't get the provider name.

```
public static String getWifiProvider(Context context) {
    String wifiProvider;
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext()
        .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    wifiProvider = wifiInfo.getSSID();
    return wifiProvider;

}
```

Comment: Please show us anything you have tried so far

Comment: I have updated my query with my snippet. Thanks :-)